# Basic libs for scheme (queue)

Tags: scheme, racket

I've used scheme for fun, and now I'd like to try it for something serious.  While I see the educational value in implementing the basic data structures from scratch, via `car` and `cdr` and recursion, I'd like to find a "batteries included" lib for the basic containers: queue, stack, access nth item, etc, with mutation.

How can I find one?

(I'm using an old PLT Scheme; if need be, I could upgrade to Racket)

Comment: It probably would help to upgrade to Racket. Racket is its own language and has its own user-contributed libraries available in its package catalog: http://pkgs.racket-lang.org/ Plenty of data structures available. Also I did vote to close because this is technically off-topic for SO. I'd recommend asking this kind of question on #racket on IRC or on the mailing list (though check out the package listing and documentation first).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [SRFIs](http://srfi.schemers.org), there you'll find a lot of nice list procedures and data structure implementations (say, [queues](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-117/srfi-117.html)).

Also, Racket includes several basic data structures ([sets](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html), [hash tables](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html), etc.) and a rich collection of built-in [list procedures](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html), many borrowed from the above mentioned SRFIs, and anyway you can import SRFIs in Racket, for extra power.

Why the requirement of mutation? certainly you'll find mutable data structures / list operations in the SRFIs and in Racket, but that's not the idiomatic way to build programs in Scheme or Racket.

Comment: Thanks.  Why mutation? Although all the procedures are functional, I need a global queue which needs to change, which I don't feel like passing around to each procedure.

Comment: In newer Rackets also see the [`data`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/data/index.html) collection, including [an imperative queue](https://docs.racket-lang.org/data/Imperative_Queues.html).